# Where to put API related logic in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

When using Spring MVC for REST API i typically have the normal components - Repository for DB access, Service for CRUD operations, and RESTController for Web layer.

Things get out of balance when i want to add a new API that is not a typical CRUD API. For example lets say i have a Person class

```
class Person{
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private List<Person> familyMembers;
   private Address address;
   private Bank bank;
}
```

And i'd like to add a api that will be used by calling
`POST /persons/{personId}/registerToBestBank`

The method will do all sort of calculation that is very specific to it, it might register it to the bank that has most of its family members, or the one most closest to him - or some sort of complicated calculation that depends on other entities.

The RestController is the only place which will use this calcluation so it makes since to me to put it in there, and not add more APIs to the service which adds a lot of noise to the system.

Is there a best practice?

Comment: I think using the so-called `service` classes is the right place to put all of that. You can put the weight of the orchestration on that layer and leave the API one just for request/responses...which makes sense. And I totally get what you are saying, but sometimes having "some" noise is better in the long run.

Comment: The answer to your question is into `MVC` Design pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller

Answer (score 1):

API stands for Application Programming **Interface**.

As such it should be only a layer that translates the rest calls into proper calls to the service. The business logic itself should be implemented in the service layer.

Think about it this way: If one day REST is replaced by some other technology or you want to add another way to execute the same function (e.g. react on an external event etc.) you only have to implement the new API. The functionality itself, since it is implemented in the service does not have to be changed at all.

You can still separate the CRUD service functionality from any other functionality if you feel that the service gets too bloated.

If you really are 100% sure that some function is only going to be needed for the REST API you can implement it in the controller. But testing controllers can be a bit of challenge, so I would not recommend that unless you have that problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

keep your business logic in Service layer and only delegation  specific code in your controller.

**Rule of thumb :**

**Presentation Layer : Controller (@Controller)**

Only responcible for delegation to App Service

**Application Service Layer : Application Service (@Service)**

Responcible for business use cases, any business logic calculation or rules/algo etc

**Repository (@Repository) etc**

No business logic only DB operations

Answer (score 1):

Controllers should not contain any code which belongs to Service layer i.e business logic.
Even we create the microservices for better-structured way. It may vary that we can place CRUD operations in one service and can place other operation in another service if required.

*Ideal Way*

- For REST APIs request, response is the core part which should be handled by Controller
- Service should contain business login
- repository to handle DB operation
- DTO/DAO according to the requirement

*Why?*

- Structured way (cleaner and easier to understand/discover)
- Easy to write TestCases